# Compute the degree of the splitting field

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I need to compute the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_{3}$. Quite honestly I don't really know where to begin, I know the polynomial is irreducible in this field. So I thought we could consider some element $\alpha \in E$ where E is some field extensions of $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ and try to find a relation between $\alpha$ and the other roots, but I am not 100% sure. Also I think the degree is $4$ but I am not sure why. Any hints would be apprecaited. Please beare in mind that I am only a few weeks into my galois theory course so it might take a while for me  to follow.

Comment: The polynomial is a divisor of $X^5-1$ and so its roots are elements of order $5$ in some extension of $\mathbb F_3$. Now, $\mathbb F_{3^n}$ contains a fifth root of unity exactly when $3^n-1$ (the order of the multiplicative group of the field) is divisible by $5$. What is the smallest extension field that contains fifth roots of unity? We need to find the smallest $n$ such that $3^n-1$ is divisible by $5$. Just start from $n=1$ and work your way up....

Comment: ok so the smallest n such that $5\mid3^{n}-1$ is 4 so this means $\mathbb{F}_{3^{n}}$ contains a fifth root of unity according to what you said. so the smallest extension field containing fifth roots of unity is $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ ?

Comment: Yes, $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ splits in $\mathbb F_{81}$ (and extensions thereof). You don't need to work too hard at finding "relationships" between the roots of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$.  $$X^5-1 = \prod_{i=0}^4(X-\alpha^i) = (X-1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1) \Rightarrow X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1 = \prod_{i=1}^4(X-\alpha^i).$$

Comment: Ok, apologies for being so slow here but i think im starting to understand. So we have that $X^{5}-1=(X-1)(X^{5}+X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1)$ and as $X^{5}-1$ has the 5 roots of unity and so $X^{5}+X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1$ has 4 roots namely $\omega$ , $\omega^{2}$ , $-\omega$ and $-\omega^{2}$ where $\omega = e^{\dfrac{2i\pi}{5}}$ so we have splitting field $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\omega)$ so all i need to do is find the degree of the minimum polynomial for $\omega$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$? what would this polynomial be?

Comment: @user130289: What is this exponential function over $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: A very valid question which i have no idea how to answer

Comment: I was just hoping that now i know the roots and know a relationship between them i could adjoin the "generating" root if you like to the field, find a minimum polynomial for it over our original field and thus the degree of that would be the degree of the splitting field

Comment: Also apologies for the typo in my message 4 up from this one, obviously the polynomial should be $X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1$ and not the quintic which i put down

Comment: Extending a field like $\Bbb{F}_3$ is bit different from extending the rationals in the sense that we don't have a nice model of a familiar algebraically closed field like $\Bbb{C}$ where we can find the roots. We need to construct the roots while we go. But many a thing stays the same! What stays the same here is that the zeros are powers of each other. So first satisfy yourself of the fact that $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible - Martin's way of doing that is my favorite, but there are others. Then construct the field $K=\Bbb{F}_3[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, and then

Comment: (cont'd) observe that the element $\alpha=x+\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a zero of $p(x)$ (same old thing). At that point you can either directly observe that because $p(x)\mid x^5-1$, the powers $\alpha^2,\alpha^3$,$\alpha^4=-1-\alpha-\alpha^2-\alpha^3$ are the other zeros. Or you can take a Galois theoretic road and show that $\alpha^3$, $\alpha^9$,
$\alpha^{27}$ are also roots (the same set of roots actually). BTW, the latter method shows that you ALWAYS get the splitting field when you adjoin one zero of an irreducible polynomial over a finite field.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is a finite field and $f \in K[X]$ is irreducible, then $K[X]/(f)$ is a splitting field of $f$. This follows from the fact that finite extensions of finite fields are always [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension). If $\alpha$ is a root, the other roots are $\alpha^{p^n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $p=\mathrm{char}(K)$. In particular, the degree is $\mathrm{deg}(f)$.

If $n$ is a natural number coprime to $p$, then it is a fact that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ if and only if $[p]$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$.

Since $[3]$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^\times$, it follows that $\Phi_5=X^4+\dotsc+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ and hence $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ is a splitting field. Explicitly, if $\alpha$ is a root of $\Phi_5$, then the other roots are $\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4$.

Comment: But surely if $\mathbb{F}_{3^{4}}$ is a splitting field (and all splitting fields are isomorphic to one another) and the cardinality of  $\mathbb{F}_{3^{4}}$ is well $3^{4}-1$ how do we have degree 4?

Comment: sorry for the slow reply btw, thank you for your help i just need a bit more explanation as i am confused as to why the method above of trying to find the minimum polynomials degree over our constructed field would not work